# Why did my .htaccess file work fine on my local MAMP testing server, but doesn't work on my Linux production server?

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mamp

I developed a web app on my Mac using MAMP. The app uses a .htaccess file, which is contained in the root directory. Everything worked great when testing on my local MAMP environment. However, when I moved to my hosted server (dedicated server running Red Hat Linux), my rewrite rules in the .htaccess file are not working properly. For example, when a user logs in to my site the rewrite rule takes them to http://www.mysite.com/authenticate/login as it should (it appears the rewrite rule in .htaccess worked). However, I get a 404 file not found error. Can anyone see what the problem is? Here is the code in the .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
Options -indexes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `AllowOverride` directive correctly set on the production server?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: I have emailed my hosting company to find out. How should `AllowOverride` be set? I know it SHOULDN'T be set to NONE, but other than that I'm not sure. All I know is that my site works perfectly on my local MAMP setup, but will only load the homepage on my hosted server.

Comment: `AllowOverride All` would be a safe bet for you. But don't forget to __explicitly deny__ any access to the .htaccess files, as with `AllowOverride All` one can set security-related things there as well.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out `AllowOverride All` is the current setting on the server though, so that must not be the problem. Can you think of any other reason why my .htaccess file appears to not be working? I'm over 99% sure the problem is due to the .htaccess file not being recognized by the server, but I'm at a complete loss as to how to figure this out.

Comment: @JohnAnderson : other than that I can only _guess_ that there is some issue on the server with mod_rewrite. Probably it's not enabled/installed. You can check the .htaccess file by putting some very basic stuff in there, like `deny from all` and check if it changes anything.